# Change encoding (iconv in php) doesn't work

Tags: php, iconv

I have a database with data in windows-1253 encoding.
I'm trying to convert them to utf8 with iconv function and display them in a page but I get characters like these: g óôçí åðüìåíç ôáéíßá ôïõ

Any thoughts?

This is the code I use

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($this->row["question"], mb_detect_order(), true),"UTF-8",htmlentities(stripslashes($this->row["question"])))
```

Comment: Are you getting correct characters without `iconv`?

Comment: I'm getting the same characters with or without iconv. It seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: Well are you setting `windows-1253` as the charset of your connection? It seems to me like you aren't

Comment: I think it is a collation problem, because it works fine at localhost (database and tables collation: latin1-swedish-ci & latin-general-ci) but it doesn't work at the other server (database collation: utf8-unicode-ci, table: utf8-general-ci)

Comment: That's obviously the problem, but I asked whether you're setting it as the expected charset of the connection you use to your localhost

Comment: I did it. Now, I'm getting ??? instead of characters.

Comment: Okay so I just did a simple search for mysql and this is what instantly came up http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8 Try searching 'convert database charset' or something and look for the database you're using. They probably have it

Comment: I made it!
Thank you very much for your help. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you know the encoding is windows-1253, then simply try to use:

```
iconv('Windows-1253','UTF-8', $text);
```